# AZURE VM running ubuntu 16.04, looking for firewall rules

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-web-app-service, firewall, lamp

About to run an Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Azure. Normally I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Azure has a slightly confusing setup routine. VM 1... will be a LAMP system running DRUPAL. VM 2... running Docker/golang.  I'm looking for suggestions on firewall rules, perhaps some best practice to harden the systems. Any tips I should consider.

Answer (score 2):

To secure Virtual Machines in Azure, it's best to setup Network Security Groups (NSG) on the Azure Virtual Network the VM is in. This will firewall your VM at the network level and keep you from needing to configure the OS and software firewalls that someone else could change when SSH'd into the server.